# How can I list all service accounts (also those created by GCP) with the "gcloud" CLI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-iam

When using `gcloud iam service-accounts list` I only see those service accounts created by me. But for script reasons I'd like to obtain also those created by GCP.

Especially I am looking for `815330817453@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com`. Since I am creating my GCP infrastructure with terraform I can **not** depend on `815330817453` as an identifier and therefore need to look for the service account manually via `gcloud`.

However `gcloud iam service-accounts list` does not list the `cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com` service account (nor any other like compute.gserviceaccount.com`

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of important qualifications to your question.

Service Accounts have a dual role in Google Cloud Platform. Service Account are (both) resources **and** may be used as identities.

###### 1. Resource

Service Accounts are resources created in (owned by) a Google Cloud Platform project.

> **NOTE** Service Accounts may be applied to non-Project resources too and, what follows, excludes (does not include) those bindings.

A Project `foo` owns zero or more Service Accounts. For Project (`PROJECT`), these may be enumerated:

```sh
gcloud iam service-accounts list \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

###### 2. Identity

A Project `foo` includes an IAM Policy that may reference zero or more Service Accounts. These Service Accounts may be created in (owned by) **any** Google Cloud Platform project (not just the project policy in which they're referenced). These Service Accounts include Google-managed Service Accounts such as those in the domain `gserviceaccount.com`.

To enumerate these Service Accounts requires a different command. For Project (`PROJECT`), these may be enumerated:

```sh
gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT} \
--flatten="bindings[].members[]" \
--filter="bindings.members~\"serviceAccount:\"" \
--format="value(bindings.members.split(sep=\":\").slice(1))"
```

It's a little *gnarly*:

- `--flatten` breaks the `bindings` slice into easier to use chunks
- `--filter` filters the chunks to only include Service Accounts
- `--format` parses `serviceAccount:foo` into `foo`

`gcloud` provides decent filtering and formatting but, if you'd prefer a more general-purpose tool like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), then:

```sh
FILTER='
  .bindings[].members[]
  |select(. | startswith("serviceAccount:"))
  |.[15:]
'

gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT} \
--format="json" \
| jq -r "${FILTER}"
```

Explanation:

- `.binding[].members[]` for these objects
- `select(. | startswith("serviceAccount:"))` selects the `serviceAccount:`
- `.[15:]` strips the `serviceAccount:` (15) leaving the account email

Comment: Nice answer, that helps to understand **why** system service accounts are not listed (because they are not resources of the project). One improvement to the given command would be to add `| sort | uniq` at the end. As the command lists role bindings and then flattens the output, there are many duplicates in the output if we not filter them out.

Answer (score 2):

Check your IAM roles , start by adding the role IAM admin/Viewer to your user, don't forget to use the command with the filter --project
`gcloud iam service-accounts list --project=PROJECTID` .
check also the IAM&Admin interface -> Service account if you can see all service accounts, that means you can list them using the `gcloud` command , if not you're user is messing a role